# I receive the following error ReferenceError: document is not defined when running my html code in Cloud 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, referenceerror

I receive the following error when I run my javascript file:

ReferenceError: document is not defined

I bring jquery into my project within the html file in the following manner:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="indexHead">
        <div id="logoDiv">
            <p id="logo">Ada</p>
            <p id="compName">Consulting</p>
            <p id="parCompName">A Sorma Enterprises Company</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blocks">
        <div id="redBlock">
            <p id="socialContent">Social Content Marketing</p>
        </div>
        <div id="yellowBlock">
            <p id="webAndAppDev">Website and Application Development</p>
        </div>
        <div id="blueBlock">
            <p id="biContent">Business Intelligence</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="indexFoot">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

with the following javascript(jquery):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#redBlock').click(function(){
    alert('alert');
    });
});
```

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`<!doctype html>`

See [What_is_the_DOCTYPE_for_modern_HTML_documents](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_DOCTYPE_for_modern_HTML_documents.3F) , [Choosing_the_right_doctype_for_your_HTML_documents](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Choosing_the_right_doctype_for_your_HTML_documents)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(jQuery().jquery)
    $('#redBlock').click(function(){
    alert('alert');
    });
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="indexHead">
        <div id="logoDiv">
            <p id="logo">Ada</p>
            <p id="compName">Consulting</p>
            <p id="parCompName">A Sorma Enterprises Company</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blocks">
        <div id="redBlock">
            <p id="socialContent">Social Content Marketing</p>
        </div>
        <div id="yellowBlock">
            <p id="webAndAppDev">Website and Application Development</p>
        </div>
        <div id="blueBlock">
            <p id="biContent">Business Intelligence</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="indexFoot">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate that.  I actually got it up about 5 minutes after I posted this.